# Is LucenePDFDocument gone from pdfbox?

Tags: pdfbox

I'm upgrading libraries on my project and upgraded pdfbox from 0.6.7 to version 1.6.0 and can't find LucenePDFDocument class. The class is still mentioned in the documentation/tutorials on the Apache page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Lucene support was moved to a separate component within PDFBox (see [PDFBOX-752](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-752)).

You can find it under the `lucene` directory in the PDFBox source tree or as the `pdfbox-lucene` artifact on the central Maven repository. And the jars can be downloaded from sites like [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox-lucene)