# Read text from a pdf using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, netbeans, jar, pdfbox

I heard that PDFBox is the best java library for reading text from a pdf. So, I downloaded `pdfbox-1.7.1.jar`, `jempbox-1.7.1.jar` and `fontbox-1.7.1.jar` (I'm not sure the last two were necessary). I added them to my project in Netbeans.

When I try the simple example from their site:

`Document luceneDocument = LucenePDFDocument.getDocument(something)`

It won't work because `org.apache.pdfbox.searchengine.lucene` does not exist. I also tried with `pdfbox-1.4.0` and it's the same.
So, where can I find that class (is there any other jar needed that I don't know of?) or what other ways are to read text from a pdf?

**EDIT**:I found the same issue here in this [old mail](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/200408.mbox/%3C002f01c48764%2448520270%248714a8c0@ssl%3); but  the thread is old and the workaround doesn't work either.

Comment: did you add the jars to your build path?

Comment: Yes, i added them using NetBeans (import jar/folder). The jar itself doesn't contain the package, i checked.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7974003/422353